# No sound after fresh installation of Xubuntu 16.04 (Dual Boot with Windows XP)

Tags: 16.04, sound, xubuntu

I've tried a lot of different approaches but none of them is successfull, I just installed Xubuntu 16.04 in my PC (desktop), in dual boot with Windows XP and speakers are not working at all. Could you please help me? ):

EDIT: Sorry, yes, speakers work fine in Windows, and under the "Output Devices" of pavucontrol there is just "HDMI / DisplayPort (unplugged)" option. I don't remember which approaches did I try, but I'm sure the sound is not muted (? :)

This is the output of `aplay -l` in my computer.

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia_1 [HDA NVidia], device 1: ALC883 Digital [ALC883 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: install pavucontrol and change output port in "output device", also post aplay -l result (copy terminal result)

Comment: Add more details. What approaches have you tried? Do the speakers work on WinXP? The speakers use a 3.5mm jack, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In pavucontrol  **configuration** tab, check  "profile" is not set to HDMI but to analog. Also in **output device tab**, test changing  port to "headphone" or "speaker"
- Run **Alsamixer** in  a terminal (maximize window)  and using left/right arrow keys to scroll thru faders, **raise all volumes** (up/down arrow key) , **unmute** muted faders with <kbd>m</kbd> key  (muted fader have a MM label)  ,
  test changing  state of this 2 selectors in the extrem right side  (using up/down arrow keys): "**automute**" "**loopback**"   :
  usually,"**automute**" is enabled ,   "**loopback**" is disabled

(on my soundcard , no sound if loopback is enabled)

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. I set configuration and output device as you said, and checked alsamixer to max sounds, and also I had to disconnect and reconnect my speakers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is my system configuration
Ubunutu 22.04/Jammy
Asus monitor with inbuilt speaker connected via a display port

Problem statement: no audio via the monitor speakers
Resolution:

1. Install pulse audo volume control
2. Goto configuration
3. Goto HDA Nvidia> change proefile to Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output
4. Go to settings of Ubuntu
5. Goto sound settings
6. Change output device to HDMI/DisplayPort 2 - HDA Nvidia
   Test... this worked for me